# Oracle 19c installation on Rhel9 amd RHEL 8 difference

Tags: oracle, rhel8, rhel9

When I run Oracle installation using automation on rhel9, I get following error. I am using db_19.22.0.0.240228.zip

```
Launching Oracle Database Setup Wizard...

[FATAL] [INS-35955] The Database software home (/xx/yyy/oracle/product/19.0.0/xyz) is already registered in the central inventory. This tool can only be used in a non-registered Database home.
 ACTION: Choose a different location as Oracle home
```

when I run same set if steps on RHEL 8 with db_19.17.0.0.20221110.zip, Installation is successfull with following warnings

```
[WARNING] [INS-13014] Target environment does not meet some optional requirements.
   CAUSE: Some of the optional prerequisites are not met. See logs for details. /xx/yyy/oraInventory/logs/InstallActions2024-03-12_08-23-14PM/installActions2024-03-12_08-23-14PM.log
   ACTION: Identify the list of failed prerequisite checks from the log: ..../installActions2024-03-12_08-23-14PM.log. Then either from the log file or from installation manual find the appropriate configuration to meet the prerequisites and fix it manually.
The response file for this session can be found at:
/xx/yyy/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/install/response/db_2024-03-12_08-23-14PM.rsp

You can find the log of this install session at:
/xx/yyy/oraInventory/logs/InstallActions2024-03-12_08-23-14PM/installActions2024-03-12_08-23-14PM.log

As a root user, execute the following script(s):
    1. ..../product/19.0.0/db_1/root.sh
```

Any ideas on what could be causing issues with rhel9 thanks

Tried comparing it with rhel8 installation Make sure that the files are extracted to /xx/yyy/oracle/... before

Comment: Try to format your question and provide at least fragments of logfile from failed installation